# jQuery finding element in ajax response, find not working

Tags: jquery

This is my ajax call

```
jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
    var slug = $(response).find(".return_product_cat").val();
    alert(slug);
});
```

This is the html being returned

```
<input type='hidden' class='return_product_cat' value='test_cat' />
```

When i alert it says undefined but it should say `test_cat`?  How do i solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find()` searches for children,
 use `filter()`

```
var slug = $(response).filter(".return_product_cat").val();
```

Just `val()` would work too, unless there is more to the html.

Comment: There is no need of `filter`, it will be bit slower

Comment: Slower? How? Please prove it. :) Also, I have already mentioned *Just val() would work too, unless there is more to the html.* `filter()` would be needed if there is more html.

Comment: @ShaunakD Because you're calling an extra function instead of just `val()` it'll be bit slower

Comment: Doesn't matter if there is less html. <`10^-2` ms

Answer (score 2):

You don't need [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/), since the element itself is returned. [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) is used to get the descendant.

Use this:

```
var slug = $(response).val();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/up3919fg/)